# PHP - Get checkbox value Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, uniform

I'm building an app using Laravel and Twitter Bootstrap. And now i've come to a point i where want to use checkboxes. Bootstrap styles the checkboxes automatically which is nice.

But in PHP i can't get the value of the checkbox to determine whether it's checked. Bootstrap seems to use "uniform" to style the checkbox. When i exclude that file i CAN get the value of the checkbox.

I do this to get the value:

$checkbox = Input::get('checkbox', function() {return 0;});

If the input has a value, use the value, else return 0.

It works fine, except when Bootstrap styles the checkbox. With jQuery it's possible to check if the span of the checkbox has the class "checked" but I want to check server-side. But Bootstrap/Uniform doesn't apply "checked" to the checkbox itself.

Are there more people that have the same problem? Or even better, does someone have the solution for this? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried if it works without uniform? I think it bugs when you apply two frameworks on 1 element

Comment: Yes, without uniform everything works fine. Sorry, thought that that was clear. The problem is that uniform doesn't apply checked="checked" to the checkbox, but class="active" to the span replacing the checkbox. I assume that multiple people have the same problem. I still want to use uniform cause it's really easy to style form elements.

Answer (score 0):

On form submittal you can always check for the validation of the checkbox:

PHP Code:

```
<?php  if(isset($_POST['$yourName'])){};  ?>
```

HTML Code:

```
<div class="form-group input-group-sm">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="$yourName">Your Title</label>
    <div class="col-md-1 input-group-sm">
        <input id="$yourName" name="$yourName" type="checkbox" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>
```